# how to dynamic link grpc with libsystemd?

Tags: grpc, systemd

when i use grpc in another project and build the project,there's a problem

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgrpc.a(systemd_utils.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'sd_is_socket_sockaddr@@LIBSYSTEMD_233'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

i have installed this lib,but it cant be link correctly.
i build grpc using command below

```
$ cmake ../.. -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON                \
              -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release       \
              -DgRPC_ABSL_PROVIDER=package     \
              -DgRPC_CARES_PROVIDER=package    \
              -DgRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER=package \
              -DgRPC_RE2_PROVIDER=package      \
              -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package      \
              -DgRPC_ZLIB_PROVIDER=package\
```

and result looks like i have already linked it

```
-- Found RE2 via CMake.
-- Found systemd via pkg-config.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/xyzhou/xyzhou-dc3/grpc/cmake/build
```

how can i solve it
is it because of the version incompatibility or should i add something when using cmake to install grpc？